# How do I inject a function declared in the parent page into an iframe, then call it?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I can inject an iframe like this:

```
iframe.contentWindow.action...
```

However, what if I want to send a function to be declared within the iframe, and then call it?

e.g.

```
function hello(){...}
iframe.contentWindow...
```

and basically both declare and call `hello` from within the iframe?

Just to clarify, `hello`'s actions should be done inside the iframe. For example, if I put `document.getElementById("input").value="foo";` inside `hello` and then call it inside the iframe, the changes should take effect inside `input` from inside the iframe and not in the parent window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a script tag into the `<head>` section of the frame with your code in it.  The script tag can be either an external script reference or an inline script.  You will have to be same origin in order to do the injection.

```
var idoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var script = idoc.createElement("script");
script.textContent = 'document.getElementById("input").value="foo";'
idoc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: How can I convert the contents of my function into a string?

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest - you can call `.toString()` on your function to get a string representation.